# Successive throws in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a swift function that throws an error, this function is called by another one, that is called by my viewcontroller.
Is there a way to throw the error from function 1, to function 2, and catch it on my viewcontroller without having to catch it on function 2?
Some code to illustrate:

```
func function1(fail : int) throws -> Int {
    if fail < 5 {
        throw MyErrors.lessThenFiveError
    }
}

func function2(myNum : int) throws -> Int {
    do {
         let x = try function1(myNum * 2)
    } catch MyErrors.lessThenFiveError { //would like to avoid this
        throw MyErrors.lessThenFiveError
    }
}

//now my viewdidload code
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        let x = try function2(someNumber)
    } catch MyErrors.lessThenFiveError {
        MessageTheUserWithTheError
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to avoid the CATCH on the function2, and just "propagate" the error from function1 to the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can simply omit the do-catch block in the second function:

```
func function1(fail : int) throws -> Int
{
    if fail < 5 {
        throw MyErrors.lessThenFiveError
    }
}

func function2(myNum : int) throws -> Int
{
    try function1(myNum * 2)
}

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        let x = try function2(someNumber)

        // Do stuff with x
    } catch MyErrors.lessThenFiveError{
        MessageTheUserWithTheError
    }
}
```

The error that's thrown by function1 propagates back to the viewDidLoad() method.